# Executing SSIS package crashes Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssis, crash, visual-studio-2019

"Execute task" from designer itself working properly.
But when I try to execute a SSIS package from Visual Studio either by "Execute package" from Solution explorer or „Start“ from taskbar, then crashes VS.
Any thoughts what to check?
Task is simple: import txt file into sql db table

Comment: is it the only task in the package?

Comment: Your computer specification? RAM, CPU, etc...

Comment: Just import simple txt file (UTF-8) into SQL table. Execute task itself working properly, but "Execute package" crashes VS. Comp conf: 16 GB RAM, Intel I5, win 10...